# Validation doesn't working in cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in `cakephp`. I wrote a validation `ctp`file in `cakephp 2.6.7` for viewing login and logout word but the validation doesn't work.

My code is:-

```
 <?php
    if (!$authUser) {

        echo $this->element('logout-header');
    } else {
        echo $this->element('login-header');
    }
    ?>
```

How can I write validation in `ctp` file for viewing login and logout word in my page header?

Comment: What kind of validation you are talking about in `view`? What is in `$authUser`?

Comment: You don't write validation in ctp file. ctp files are used for views

Comment: where did you get `$authUser` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you wrote a validation ctp? put your validation rules in model

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

In your AppController's `beforeRender()` callback set the `authUser` view variable by retrieving the logged in user:-

```
public function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    $this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());
}
```

Then the view code in your question should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution, which I regularly use when I worked in cakephp.

in AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller{

     public function beforeFilter() {
          parent::beforeFilter();
          $userInfo = array();
          if($this->Auth->user('_id')){
               $userInfo['User'] = $this->Auth->user();
               Configure::write($userInfo);
          }
     }
}
```

And after this in view `.ctp` file

```
<?php
   $authUser = Configure::read('User');
   if (!$authUser) {
       echo $this->element('logout-header');
   } else {
       echo $this->element('login-header');
   }
?>
```